# restore the default checkout in magento 2.3

Tags: layout, magento2.3, theme, template

I have a disaster in the template of a checkout, it is really bad!. I never used Magento but now I need to restore the default checkout layout/html/template of a web.

I no have backups of changes and really I don't know where to start modifying files. I search in `module-checkout` but I really don't know how to do it.

I have in other server a fresh installation of Magento 2.3 so I can copy-paste files but i don't know what files I need to copy-paste.

All the other things in the web are Okay, only the visual of Checkout are broken.

Thanks

Comment: You have to just copy vendor/magento/module-checkout folder from fresh Magento 2.3 and paste in your current server. After that run all command. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do these things so your checkout will be working fine with default files.

- Copy vendor/magento/module-checkout to /vendor/module-checkout and replace all files.
- after that run below commands

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

After this your default layout will be back. (also please check if you are using any custom theme then `app/design/frontend/[them_vendor]/[theme_name]/en_US/Magento_Checkout` directory exist if yes then remove it so it will be used from core files.